# Treat directory as request for a PHP file

Tags: php, directory

**This question is related to PHP**

How do I make a request to a directory on my server (that doesn't exist) become treated as a variable.. For example:

**domain.com/username** will really be a request to **domain.com/profile.php?user=username**

Is this even possible? Or how does YouTube/Twitter/Facebook do it?

Comment: You need to use mod rewrite for this.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the term. How exactly do you mean?

Comment: What web server software are you using? Apache? Node JS? Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff, this is called "friendly URL" and is done with url rewrite. I recommend reading this documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

If you are not familiar with regular expressions you shoud read http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

If you using apache as web server create a `.htaccess` file on your directory with following content to achieve this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for mod rewrite. Heres a short [tutorial](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)

Most PHP frameworks have libraries that make this much easier, your best bet is probably to use one of them.